# XMPP last received/sent message is not archieving

Tags: ios, iphone, xmpp

I am doing an XMPP iPhone chat application for the first time (using XMPP framework from gitHub). On that I can able to send and receive messages, but my problem is :

Now I am on the chatting page, on that I have used a method to fetch all the archived messages from XMPPMessageArchivingCoreDataStorage and displaying it to the user. 
When a new message arrives "xmppStream: didReceiveMessage:" method will get called and on that I have posted a notification. Receiver of that notification is set on the chatting page. So when a new message notification arrives I use the same previous method to fetch the archived messages and then display it to the user. I have done this for showing the new message to the user.
But my problem is that when Message 1 arrives it's not listing, then Message 2 arrives Message 1 listing, when Message 3 arrives Message 1 and 2 are listing and so on. But some times it works fine.

My doubts are :

1. Is this the correct way to display new messages ?
2. If yes, why the last message is not archiving some times ?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for posting notifications when a new message arrived. For that we can use NSFetchedResultsController.

I have fixed the issue by using NSFetchedResultsController for managing the XMPPMessageArchivingCoreDataStorage and tableview.

[See more about NSFetchedResultsController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsController_Class/)

Answer (score 0):

You mean that all message is received ?
If that's it,you just add all messages into a List and then inform the Table to update the data.To make sure it work,Add a dispatch_async in your code.

Comment: I am thinking that when a new message arrives first it saves to the core-data. So I am fetching all the messages from the coredata and trying to display it. On such a scenario the last message is not getting from the coredata